# How would I add a vertical aligned bar to a li with horizontal content?

Tags: html, css

Hard to articulate question, so better to have an image example.

I want to have a vertical column on a HTML list of li's where the date is always rotated and my content is to the right.  I have a partial working copy, but its hack-y.

[image]

Comment: I have this jsFiddle for it.  http://jsfiddle.net/fyNn2/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2GSBu/2/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="date">May 24, 2014</div>
<ul>
    <li>Bob Hope</li>
    <li>Dr Who</li>
    <li>Disney Land</li>
    </ul>
</div>

ul {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {

    margin-left: 60px;
    list-style: none;

}

.date {
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;


}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a working example.  Sorry, i wasn't clear in my original posting, but each date bar is in each line item, not just the top.  Here is my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fyNn2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use tranform: rotate(-90deg); check this css-tricks article

This rotates text 90 degrees counterclockwise.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

You can see working demo here
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation
http://css-tricks.com/date-display-with-sprites/

Comment: yes, i'm using that exact rotate class now to rotate that element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

http://jsfiddle.net/B7KfU/1/

```
<ul>
    <li class="songs">
        <div class="dates">May 24</div>
        <div class="details">Bob hope</div>
    </li>
    <li class="songs">
        <div class="dates">May 24</div>
        <div class="details">Bob hope</div>
    </li>
</ul>


ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    height: 70px;
}

div{
    display:inline-block;
}

.dates{
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translate( -50%,0);
  transform-origin:0.35em center;
  background-color:#333;
  color:white;
  padding-right:16px;
  padding-left:7px;
  font-size:11px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the dates column rotated, yet i do see the rotate css in your example